# 24 bit HX711 ADC Reading

Tags: adc

How to read [24-bit HX711 ADC](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) data using AT89S52 micro-controller, can anybody help me to understand? How I will store 24-bit data in micro-controller?

Comment: You can easily store 24 bits in the AT89S52’s internal RAM of 256 bytes (=2048 bits). As for how to read those bits from the HX711 ADC, you should consult its datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the **datasheet**:

In the sections serial interface you can see the description of the method used to retrieve data from the ADC. Below snapshot is for reference:.

1. DOUT should be connected to your MCU GPIO input pin. A low on this pin indicates that,the data is ready in the ADC.
2. PD_CLK is the GPIO output pin. You have to then send pulses on this pin while simultaneously reading the DOUT pin status.
3. Depending on the gain set and the channel selected the number of pulses needed will vary.
4. At the end of the data, SOUT line will go high again.
5. So, This doesn't seem to be a standard interface. You have to develop your own bit bang style code for this
6. You have to also take care of accumulating the 24 bits and combining it into one interpretable value.[image]

Please post specific question if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to work out how to read the three bytes of each measurement from the HX711. My understanding is the part uses a non-standard two wire interface. You may want to check the web site for one of the vendors that makes a breakout board for the HX711 as they typically will include library code for use with an off the shelf MCU board like an Arduino.

Once you have gathered the three bytes of each reading you will need to store those values so that you can use them in the software that you will create for your MCU. If you are working in an assembly language environment you would store the three bytes into memory of the MCU in three sequential bytes of the memory. The order that you store them would be dictated by the software routines you would create for dealing with 24-bit numerical values. A little endian order would store as:

Addr N+0 - Bits [7:0]

Addr N+1 - Bits [15:8]

Addr N+2 - Bits [23:16]

A bit endian order would store the bytes in the opposite order.

If you are working in a high level language such as C you would want to store the bytes into a format compatible with the multi-byte data type supported by the language. In C there will typically be a 32-bit data type such as a **long** or **unsigned long**. You would move the three bytes to the low three ordered bytes of a variable of the 32-bit type. It the data from the HX711 is unsigned data then just set the bits [31:24] of the variable to zeros. It the data is signed format data then you would want to sign extend the 24-bit value into the 32-bit variable. This is done by setting all bits in [31:24] to the same value as from bit [23] of the HX711 reading value. Once you have the value on the 32-bit variable you can program using the math features of the language to manipulate and calculate.